# Allowing certain users to edit drop-down list values

Tags: ms-access

**Current situation:**

I've created a purchase orders database application for a company in MS Access.

- The data is stored in a back-end database on a server.
- There is a front-end master copy on a shared drive. Local copies are automatically pushed out to users when they login. Users use their own local front-end application.

As well as the two main data tables, there are several other tables containing lists of suppliers, project codes *etc.*, which are used as suggestions in the drop-down lists on the forms. At first, I had these as linked tables as well, but performance was slow. Each drop-down box would take a few seconds to load.

Now, these tables are embedded into the front-end. My idea was that people who need to edit these tables could do so within the master copy of the front end. I have built forms to add / remove codes and suppliers from the lists.

However, this solution is not going to work as-is. The master file is a pre-compiled .accde file, so when I need to create a new version (from my master .accdb file) any changes made to the lists will be lost.

**Current idea:**

To have two copies of the 'auxiliary' tables in the database - one linked locally ("C:\Databases") and one to a master copy on the server. The forms would populate from the local copy. The editing section would alter the server copy. On login, the server auxiliary tables would be pushed to everyone's local drives along with the app.

This seems awfully complex for what isn't a complex situation. It also brings about strange consequences for the user; editing the tables doesn't actually do anything to the application until they next login (and sync the tables).

---

Am I going about this the right way? Surely there is a better way of handling this sort of requirement?

Comment: Consider migrating your back end server to SQL Server Express; it offers far better reliability and performance than an Access back-end database will ever get you.  You should be able to store lists of drop-down values at the server with no noticeable delay using SQL Server backend.

Comment: Assuming you cannot do a SQL Server backend; you may want to try putting the tables for drop-down items in their own Access database at the server and see if that makes it faster.

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server is not an option here. I will try your second method and report back -- hopefully the drop-down items tables will indeed load faster if in a separate database than the main data. Thanks!

Comment: How many users are using the front end?

Comment: Probably not more than five concurrently, up to 100 in total. Each user has their own local copy, however.

Comment: I asked that since concurrency can be problematic when accessing Access tables across the network, since Access will want to lock the entire table until the combo box has "seen" all the relevant rows.  One way to get around this problem is to force the combo box to select the last item on Form Open.

Comment: I think I've found the best solution for this. The auxiliary tables are in their own database on the server, which is linked. However, they are copied to a separate local temporary database when a) the app is opened or b) the server copies are updated from within the app.

The temp database is deleted when the app is closed.

Much of the code came from [this ExpertsExchange answer](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/A_9753-Creating-and-using-Temporary-Tables-in-Microsoft-Access.html), which I was able to view for free once but is now sadly behind a pay gate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17032/discussion-between-mark-butler-and-max-vernon).